# У тега div не убирается отступ

Tags: html, вёрстка

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <img src="img/Nado.jpg" alt="" id="imgtovara">
  <div id="nazvanye">
    Название товара
  </div>

  <style>
    #imgtovara {
      width: 550px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 2px dotted;
      border-radius: 6.25%;
    }
    
    #nazvanye {
      width: 127px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: какой отступ? ()

Comment: Мне не понять откуда у вас отступ перед дивом. Если вы имеете ввиду отступ в исходниках, то скорее всего вас редактор с включенным форматированием. Возьмите блокнот и отредактируйте там либо выключите форматирование. Но всё это только форматирование. Как я упомянул я не вижу пробелов в исходниках.

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Вы про пробел в коде? Обычно так делают автоматически редакторы кода. Проверила в отображении отступ, его там тоже нет. Уточните, пожалуйста вопрос. И, если речь все-таки шла об отступе в коде, воспользуйтесь блокнотом, как вам и посоветовал человек сверху)